# IntelliJ Idea Run Option Missing

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-15

My IntelliJ Idea was running totally fine until suddenly when I used the Run Command it was not compiling for long period of time  , then on right clicking the option to Run which would usually come just dissapeared. Can anyone tell me why ?

[image: 1]

1. Tried Closing and Opening the IDE , not working.
2. Deleted Cache from the memory no result.

Comment: The run option is missing because there is [Indexing](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/indexing.html) process running in the top-right corner of the editor. How much time does it take to complete indexing? If it never finishes, try to [disable all third-party plugins](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html#disable-plugin) and restart. Actions `File | Invalidate Caches...`, and `File | Repair IDE` may also help.

Comment: If none of the above steps worked please contact JetBrains support [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new), and provide the [IDE logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085) for further processing.